# how to apply condition based custom segue in storyboard

Tags: xcode, conditional-statements, segue, uistoryboard

i am working on storyboards which has couple of views on first view a condition is placed i want if the condition satisfies then only navigation should happen

For this i have used Custom segue but no matter my condition satisfies or not it navigates to new view.

I have created method in custom segue class

```
- (void) perform{

    NSLog(@"source %@",self.sourceViewController);
    NSLog(@"dest %@",self.destinationViewController);

    UIViewController *sVC=self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dVC=self.destinationViewController;

    [sVC.navigationController pushViewController:dVC animated:YES];


}
```

I want to set condition if result is 1 then only it should navigate. Woul prepareforsegue or initwithsegue provide me any help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you saying that you only want to perform the segue if a condition is true?

If so, instead of creating the segue directly from a control or table cell, create a triggerless segue. A triggerless segue has the view controller as its source, and it won't ever fire automatically. Instead you can fire it programmatically any time you like, including from an IBAction.

To create a triggerless segue, start control+dragging the segue from the containing view controller icon in the scene dock at the bottom of the scene. Drag to the destination scene like normal, and pick the segue type. Select the segue, and in the inspector, choose a segue identifier.

At runtime, when you want to perform the segue, invoke -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]. You can pass any object you'd like for the sender, including nil. If the sender has no use to you, pass nil.

So, in summary:

- Create a triggerless segue from the view controller to the destination scene
- Set an identifier for the segue in the inspector
- At runtime, and form code, call -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] when you want to trigger the segue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you plz tell me that the movement i drag from source to destination it shows me push,modal,custom and i select the custom and give this segue an identifier   But as i have set its identifier then it will forcefully call the the segue class method on click of the button how will it check the condition

Comment: hi Jon, i applied as you said and now it pushes twice i created a push segue and set it identifier when i click on the button i wrote [UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] method  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JHCustomSegue" sender:nil];     can you please chk wat i am doing wrong here

Comment: Hi finally i found the solutio Hope it help others                           You can manually perform segues. When you create a segue in the storyboard, instead of Ctrl+Dragging from a button to a View Controller, drag from the View Controller to another View Controller. Give the segue a name, then in your code you call [self performseguewithidentifier@"seguename"]

Comment: Yep, that's what I was describing with the triggerless segue above, sorry I wasn't more clear. I'm glad you got things working.

Comment: How i can pass data in this case between viewcontrollers?