# Creating a conditional segue

Tags: iphone, ios, segue

I want to have a main view controller which checks if a user has already logged in. If so, it segues to a tab view controller. If not, it segues to a login view controller which handles the login and then segues to the tab view controller.

To test just the segue aspect of the a feature out, I created a separate project. I have created 3 view controllers - all subclasses of UIViewController. One of them is a main view controller and the other two are simple view controllers to which the conditional segue should happen.

I read about creating "triggerless" segue in the thread [how to apply condition based custom segue in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827203/how-to-apply-condition-based-custom-segue-in-storyboard)

How do I create two triggerless segues such that I manually choose to execute only one of the two at run time depending on if the user is logged in or not? Or is there a different way of achieving this rather common scenario?

Comment: Is there a button or some other UI element in the main view controller that leads to the activation of one of the two segues?

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. No, there is no button which is why it is triggerless. I have solved the problem though. For some reason, I was not able to create a segue from the source view to second view and assumed that you can only create one segue. I tried it again and it worked. Since my segue was "push", I had to embed the source view controller in navigation view controller. Got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create two triggerless segues such that I manually choose to execute only one of the two at run time depending on if the user is logged in or not?

- Create the first triggerless segue leading to the logon screen; give it an identifier, say, `needLogin`
- Create the second triggerless segue leading to the tab view; give it an identifier, say, `whenLoggedIn`
- Define an action in the main view controller, and put this code in its associated method:

```
// This is attached to the button on the main screen
-(void)onCheckLogin {
    if (userIsLoggedIn) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whenLoggedIn" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"needLogin" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I arrived at the same conclusion myself - but marking your answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to check whether is logged in or logged out.
Try with this :

```
if (loggedIn) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToViewController1" sender:self];
} else if (loggeOut) {
    // Segue to Login viewController 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToLoginViewController" sender:self];
}
```

Note : In stoyboard, you have to create segue from your viewController only, not from a UIButton or any other object from where segue is possible.